# d3.js radially position elements around an object

Tags: d3.js, data-visualization

I'm currently stuck at a problem with d3.js regarding the positioning.

This is the code I have right now

```
 var center = {name: "sun", count: 20 }; //Will have more complex data in the future

 var planets = [
    {name: "Mercury", count: 2},
    {name: "Venus", count: 3} ,
    {name: "Earth", count: 5},
    {name: "Mars", count: 4},
    {name: "Jupiter", count: 11},
    {name: "Saturn", count: 10},
    {name: "Uranus", count: 7},
    {name: "Neptune", count: 8} ];

 var svg = d3.select("#planet-chart").append("svg")
    .attr("width", 800)
    .attr("height", 800);


 var circleContainer = svg.selectAll("g mySolarText")
     .data(planets);


 var circleContainerEnter = circleContainer.enter()
     .append("g")
     .attr("transform", function(d,i){
         return "translate("+ i*10 +",80)"
     });

 var circle = circleContainerEnter.append("circle")
      .attr("r", function(d){return d.count * 5} )
      .attr("cx", function(d,i){return (i+1) * 30} )
      .attr("cy", function(d,i){return (i+1) * 30} )
      .attr("stroke","black")
      .attr("fill", "white");


  circleContainerEnter.append("text")
       .attr("dx", function(d){return -20})
       .text(function(d){
          return d.name}
        );
```

[image: output solar system current vs desired]

Issues I am having right now are:

1. Currently, I can only pass the planets variable into the circle container, but I wish to also include the sun variable into it but I do not know how. I cannot simply include the sun variable into the planets array variable because I will need to put more data into it in the future.
2. I am having a hard time trying to figure out how to radially position the 
   planets around the sun, and add connecting lines to them which I am hoping to do. I have tried looking into arc but I am stuck.

For now, the sizes of the planets are being adjusted with their count values which I just multiply with the radius. Forgive me I am just a student and wish to learn more about d3 js. If you guys can help me, I would be so much grateful. Or if you can lead me to references I would be so much indebted.

Thank you so much in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@tomshanley helped me via d3 official help forums. he posted this code for the fix to the issues I was encountering.

http://blockbuilder.org/tomshanley/840d381a9ca87ab404f63adda1ba8452

```
const radians = 0.0174532925

var center = {name: "sun", count: 20 };

var planets = [
      {name: "Mercury", count: 2},
      {name: "Venus", count: 3} ,
      {name: "Earth", count: 5},
      {name: "Mars", count: 4},
      {name: "Jupiter", count: 11},
      {name: "Saturn", count: 10},
      {name: "Uranus", count: 7},
      {name: "Neptune", count: 8} ];

 var w = 800, h = 800;

 var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
      .attr("width", w)
      .attr("height", h);

let orbitRadius = d3.scaleLinear()
    .domain([0,8]) //number of planets
    .range([90,w/2]) //you may need adjust this later

let angle = d3.scaleLinear()
    .domain([0,9]) //number of planets + 1
    .range([0,360]) //you may need adjust this later



svg.selectAll("line")
    .data(planets)
    .enter()
    .append("line")
    .attr("x1", function(d,i){

    let a = angle(i);
    let r = orbitRadius(i);

    return xCoord = x(a, r) + (w/2)

 })
    .attr("y1", function(d,i){

    let a = angle(i);
    let r = orbitRadius(i);

    return yCoord = y(a, r) + (h/2)

 })
    .attr("x2", (w/2))
    .attr("y2", (h/2))
    .style("stroke", "black")
    .style("stroke-width", 2)



 var circleContainer = svg.selectAll("g mySolarText")
     .data(planets);

 var circleContainerEnter = circleContainer.enter()
     .append("g")
     .attr("transform", function(d,i){

    let a = angle(i);
    let r = orbitRadius(i);

    let xCoord = x(a, r) + (w/2)
    let yCoord = y(a, r) + (h/2)

    return "translate("+ xCoord +"," + yCoord + ")"
 });

var circle = circleContainerEnter.append("circle")
  .attr("r", function(d){return d.count * 5} )
  .attr("cx", 0)
  .attr("cy", 0)
  .attr("stroke","black")
  .attr("fill", "white");

circleContainerEnter.append("text")
   .attr("dx", function(d){return -20})
   .text(function(d){
      return d.name}
    );

function x (angle, radius) {
  // change to clockwise
  let a = 360 - angle
  // start from 12 o'clock
  return radius * Math.sin(a * radians)
}

function y (angle, radius) {
  // change to clockwise
  let a = 360 - angle
  // start from 12 o'clock
  return radius * Math.cos(a * radians)
}
```

again, thanks so much! :)